# Data Partitioning in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm playing around with neo4j - seeing what I can and can't do with it before suggesting it for something serious. One of the things I'm looking at now is Data Partitioning. By this I mean having a single data store that contains data from many different customers, and knowing which customer the data belongs to.

In the SQL world, we've always done this by having a customer_id field on the tables that are customer specific, and then always including that in the queries and indices. This works perfectly well for us, but in the Graph DB world it feels like we can do better.

The options that I've come up with some far are:

1. The same as before - including a property on the nodes that is the Customer ID
2. Storing a Label on each Node that identifies the Customer. However, as far as I can tell you can't bind parameters to labels so this would mean that the queries are generated slightly awkwardly.
3. Storing a Customer Node, and linking all of the other nodes to it.

Number #3 seems to be the "correct" Graph DB way of managing this, but I'm concerned with the impact of this on the performance of the data. It's perfectly feasible that there will be hundreds of thousands of links from a single Customer Node to the other data nodes, and there will be hundreds of different Customer Nodes. (Based on the volume of data in the existing SQL database)

What's the recommended way of achieving this level of data partitioning whilst maintaining performance?

Comment: You're correct that #3 is the preferred means of modeling this in a graphdb, but it would help to know what other kinds of data (nodes) you'll be associating with this. Keep in mind that just because something is associated with a customer doesn't mean it must have a direct relationship to it. Sometimes intermediary nodes help provide additional grouping and context, as well as separation to keep the number of direct relationships down.

Comment: It's a library management system. As an example of a limited set of data, take Bibs, Items, Patrons and Holds. Bibs are global data, whereas the rest are per-customer data. The links are therefore: Item -> Bib, Item -> Customer, Patron -> Customer, Hold -> Bib, Hold -> Patron. It's often the case that a single Customer will have tens or hundreds of thousands of Items, and easily have thousands of Patrons.

Comment: I'm going against the grain of what @InverseFalcon stated:  I *don't* think there's a preferred means of modeling this. We simply have no idea of your data or query needs. And if you have a need to do cross-customer queries, #3 falls short. This type of question is simply too broad and opinion-soliciting for StackOverflow.

Comment: With more information about the data model and the use cases, I think it is possible to formulate recommendations. There have been many other questions of the same type in SO for neo4j.

Comment: @Graham: What is the difference between a "Patron" and a "Customer"? And can you provide details about your most important use case(s)? For example, when a hold is placed, what is being "held" (a Bib, an Item, or something else)? More details like this will make it more likely that you get any answers.

Comment: A Customer is a Library. It's the Data Partition. All of the data in the system is either Global Data (Bibs) or else pertains to a single Customer. A Patron is one of the people who borrows items from the library. Items are the individual books on the shelves that Patrons want to borrow. Bibs are the metadata about the books - things like Title, Author, etc. One Bib may have many Items, for many Customers. Holds are placed on a Bib or an Item, and are an indication that a Patron wants that book at some point soon. If on the Bib then it's for any Item the Customer owns links to that Bib.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify my comment concerning the options you enumerated. #2 is mostly out due to the reasons you cited. #1 tends to be a holdover from those coming from SQL...that is, using foreign keys and a join-like approach between nodes instead of relationships between nodes (with relationships between nodes as how I interpreted #3). That said, those are merely some guidelines. David is correct that your data and query needs should ultimately define your modeling, though I think using :Customer nodes somewhere in your model shouldn't prevent cross-customer queries.